# How to see errors on production mode - nuxtjs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I think there are many questions about this.
But there isn't a correct answer.
How I can see detail of error logs on production mode?

[image]

Comment: Dont understand your question. As it is told you see the errors in the logs

Comment: How I can see detail of error?

Comment: That means server-side logs, not something that would pop up in your browser console. How are you running your app?

Comment: You can use Sentry to capture the errors in production. There is a Nuxt package for that too: https://sentry.nuxtjs.org/guide/setup/

Answer (score 2):

You should debug it locally before shipping to production because this may be fixable locally.
Otherwise, [Sentry](https://sentry.io/welcome/)/[Logrocket](https://logrocket.com/) are good solutions, on top of a whole testing CI.
A staging URL replicating the production environment is also a viable solution.

Otherwise, you should not have publicly visible logs accessible from the public.

Answer (score 2):

Nuxt provides a flag to enable debugging on production in the `nuxt.config.js` file

```js
{
  debug: true
}
```

Comment: This setting allows browser's console.log() in the production mode.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able the see the server logs from terminal you started the server(npm run start / nuxt start etc.). If you want the dev console in production mode, add this to your nuxt.config.js

```
  build: {
    terser:{
      terserOptions: {
        compress:{
          drop_console: false,
        },
      },
    },
  },
```